# Click handler not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a simple jQuery code that should log something to the console, but it doesn't do anything. This is my code:

```
<a class="header_contact" id="trigger_kontakt">Kontakt</a>
<a class="header_search"><img id="trigger_suche" src="someimage.jpg" /></a>
```

```js
$("#trigger_kontakt").click(function() {
  console.log("Kontakt");
  (".contact_box").addClass("active");
  (".search_box").removeClass("active");
});
```

The JS code is loaded correctly and it is loaded AFTER the reference of jQuery; but I don't get anything logged to the console - why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Has to be something with your config, because it works for me fine.

Comment: Do you have your code wrapped in document.ready function?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your selectors are missing the `$`, eg `$('.contact_box')`

Comment: No error in the console. no.
Not wrapped in document ready-function. no.

Comment: Well if you loaded jQuery properly, executed your code after the DOM was loaded, and fixed the missing `$`'s then it would work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wd079ogv/. So your example isn't a [mcve]

Comment: If that is truly your code, `(".contact_box").addClass("active");` should have thrown a TypeError: ".contact_box".addClass is not a function.

Comment: It does now, after I wrapped things into a documentready-wrapper indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code can't run,the $ is missing.

```js
$("#trigger_kontakt").click(function() {
console.log("Kontakt");
$(".contact_box").addClass("active");
$(".search_box").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
}

div{ width:100px;height:50px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="header_contact" id="trigger_kontakt">Kontakt</a>
<a class="header_search">Search</a>

<br>
<div class='contact_box'>.contact_box</div>
<div class='search_box'>.search_box</div>
```

Comment: Even without `$` it will log `Kontakt` to the console.

Comment: because javascript is an interpretor not an compiler.it compile& execute step by step per statement.I'm not good at english.for more you can see [interpretor laugnage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: I want to say javascript without previously compiling a program into machine-language instructions.so console also could be print the message before the errors throws.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try listening of the document is ready by putting your code in like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: it seems though to have something to do with it. As in his example I do get "ready!" logged and after wrapping my code into the documentready-function also my other things logged.

Why is that?

Comment: A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready